# How can I set a value in a combo box in a grid editor

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, grid, setvalue

I have been looking for days and I haven´t found anything yet. I also have tried some codes I developed just like:

```
me.comboEstudios =  me.getGestionRrhh().down('#pestanaTrabajador').down('#pestanaDatosBasicos').down('#nivelEstudios');                                         

                me.comboEstudios.getStore().load({
                    scope: this,
                    callback: function(records, operation, success) {

                        me.comboEstudios.setValue(respJson[0]['NIVEL_ESTUDIO']);                            
                    }
                });
```

but it seems like this code works well for setting values in combo boxes in forms but it doesn't work for combo box in a grid.

If someone knows how to do this, I would appreciate

Comment: I suppose what you want is to select one of the items in the combobox list. To do this use select ()

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage it in `beforeedit` event, in my case I am using `ptype: 'cellediting'` and below is my code:-

`plugins: [{
    ptype: 'cellediting',
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    listeners: {
        edit: 'cellEditingBlur',
        beforeedit: function (editor, context, eOpts) {
            var empDesignation = Ext.getStore('employeedesignation');
            if (empDesignation && !empDesignation.isLoaded()) {
                empDesignation.load();
            }
        }
    }
}],`

Hope it helps :)